# Giclee Printing on Vellum Paper

Tags: printer, ink-jet, epson

I recently acquired some vellum that is inkjet compatible, but have found precious  little information regarding printer settings for this paper beyond "...choose a setting that uses LESS ink...".  I am using an Epson 3880.  Can anyone offer advice for the printer settings that would be optimal with this paper printer combination? The paper thickness is 0.004".

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper type selector in Epson settings. The paper selection which yields fewest ink usage is "plain paper". If you are getting too wet print nonetheless, try brightening the image via settings, this will result in smaller ink usage:

- select "ColourControls" mode of "Color management" subwindow in "Advanced" tab
- in "settings" located nearby, increase "Brightness" - experiment with this to get desired result
- select AdobeRGB from "color mode" list and Gamma 2.2
- "let printer manage colours" (make sure that printing program uses AdobeRGB as a printer profile)